# Group by similarity in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table with several entries that are mostly equal, except for some tokens in them. These are messages returned from a web service and they must be stored this way.

Given this example query:

```
SELECT entry_error.error_desc, 
       Count(entry_error.id) 
FROM   entry_message err_entries 
       full outer join entry_error 
                    ON err_entries.id = entry_error.id 
       full outer join error_code 
                    ON entry_error.error_code = error_code.error_code 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id_father 
                      FROM   entry_message creator 
                      WHERE  err_entries.id = creator.id_father) 
GROUP  BY entry_error.error_desc;
```

I get an output like this:

```
entry_error.error_desc                              count(entry_error.id)                
First Sample Text: 321; Second Sample Text: 123;    1
First Sample Text: 456; Second Sample Text: 654;    1 
First Sample Text: 789; Second Sample Text: 987;    1
```

But I'd like it to be something like:

```
entry_error.error_desc                              count(entry_error.id)                
First Sample Text: {0}; Second Sample Text: {1};    3
```

Is it possible to do this directly in my query?

EDIT: Notice that the messages are just a sample and there are several different ones. They cannot be explicitly written in the query.
I need the query to group similar generic messages, (using something like UTL_MATCH, idk), that are X% similar.

Comment: Do you have to do this in a single SQL statement? If not maybe it would be easier to use PL/SQL or whatever language you are using to do this with multiple SQL statements. I'm thinking that you could choose a single row and then remove all the rows with JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY > 90 adding up the error counts. Just loop through pulling a new row out and removing all its similar rows until there are no rows left.

Answer (score 2):

> I think this is close to what you are looking for -

```
WITH ERR AS (
    SELECT
        'FIRST SAMPLE TEXT: 321; SECOND SAMPLE TEXT: 123;' AS ERR_DESC,
        1 AS ERR_COUNT
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
        'FIRST SAMPLE TEXT: 456; SECOND SAMPLE TEXT: 654;' AS ERR_DESC,
        1 AS ERR_COUNT
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
        'FIRST SAMPLE TEXT: 789; SECOND SAMPLE TEXT: 987;' AS ERR_DESC,
        1 AS ERR_COUNT
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
        'FIRST ERROR MESSAGE: 333; SECOND ERROR MESSAGE: 432;' AS ERR_DESC,
        1 AS ERR_COUNT
    FROM
        DUAL
) SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(ERR_DESC,': [0-9]*;','{0}') AS MSG,
    SUM(ERR_COUNT) AS ERROR_COUNT
FROM
    ERR
GROUP BY
    REGEXP_REPLACE(ERR_DESC,': [0-9]*;','{0}');
```

> Output -

```
"MSG","ERROR_COUNT"
"FIRST SAMPLE TEXT{0} SECOND SAMPLE TEXT{0}",3
"FIRST ERROR MESSAGE{0} SECOND ERROR MESSAGE{0}",1
```

Comment: Good answer. It almost works, but my main issue is that new messages can enter the database anytime. The tokens can vary from values like 12345678988 to to things like (-1288.84). Using regex isn't a reliable way to group these values.

I think the best solution would be something using string similarity algorithms. Using UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY I found out that the strings I want to group score 90+ similarity. However, I can't find a way to use this information to group the strings in my query.